# Excel Formula for comparing data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Would anyone be able to give me a helping hand in figuring out the formula I need for the the following?

Column F of 'workbook 1' contains Account Numbers.

Column A of 'workbook 2' contains Account Numbers.  Column E of 'workbook 2' contains Sales Rep numbers.

I need a formula that will compare Column F's cells from 'workbook 1' with Column A's cells from 'Workbook 2'.  If the cells match, data from Column E of 'workbook 2' should transfer over to a blank column H.

Comment: Did you mean **WorkSheet**? If not you need the sheet names as well as the workbooks.

Answer (score 1):

the formula should be as follow: VLOOKUP(F1 of workbook1, A:E of workbook 2, 5, false), this formula should be use on column H

Answer (score 1):

The function that you're looking for is VLOOKUP.  Try putting something like this in column H of workbook 1:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,'[workbook 2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$E$100,5,FALSE)
```

Replace "workbook 1" with the actual name of the workbook, "Sheet1" with the name of the sheet, and 100 with the number of rows in workbook 2.  You can then copy this function down the column as needed.